# Installing Contact Form with Google reCAPTCHA v2 / User's IP Address

Tags: php, recaptcha, contact-form

I'm not the best with PHP, and having a bit of a problem installing a contact form with Google reCAPTCHA v2.

There's a bit of code in one of the linked PHP files that allows the reCAPTCHA form to work. I understand most of it, but I'm unsure what to put in the "REMOTE_ADDR" part below.

```
    if ($validate_captcha) {
    require dirname(__FILE__)."/reCaptcha/autoload.php";

    // Create an instance of the service using your secret
    $re_captcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);

    // If file_get_contents() is locked down on your PHP installation to disallow
    // its use with URLs, then you can use the alternative request method instead.
    // This makes use of fsockopen() instead.
    // $re_captcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\SocketPost());

    **// Make the call to verify the response and also pass the user's IP address
    $valid_captcha = $re_captcha->verify($captcha, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);**

    if (!$valid_captcha->isSuccess()) {
        echo '<div class="error-message unit"><i class="fa fa-close"></i>Oops! Are you a robot?</div>';
        exit;
    }
}
```

Do I need to include my company's IP Address? The problem with that is we have multiple IP Addresses. How would I choose which one to include, or is there a way to list all of them?

Or, is this for the USER'S IP Address (I know it says that in the code, but I'm a little confused)? How would I know that, and do I even need to write anything in the "REMOTE_ADDR" slot at all?

Any help is much appreciated, as I've never dealt with this before. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm using CF7 since a long time now, and i'm pretty sure you don't need to code anything to make it work. Look at the configuration of CF7 you've got a part with a link explaining everything to make it work without touching the code

Comment: the Google's reCAPTCHA ask for the user's IP (optional), you don't have to include it in order for it to work.